# TitlePageIndicator: Title text not appearing or hidden on top of activity layout.(Viewpager,Xml)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-xml, viewpagerindicator

**ViewPagerFragment.java**

```
package nsixty.crew.app;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator;
import com.viewpagerindicator.TitleProvider;

public class ViewPagerFragment extends FragmentActivity {

    private CustomFragmentAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager pager;
    TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.lcmeter);

        this.initialisePaging();

    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

        fragments
                .add(Fragment.instantiate(this, LoginActivity.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, main.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter = new CustomFragmentAdapter(
                super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titles);
        titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);

    }

    public static class CustomFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
            implements TitleProvider {
        public static final int POSITION_PAGE_1 = 0;
        public static final int POSITION_PAGE_2 = 1;
        public static final int POSITION_PAGE_3 = 2;
        private List<Fragment> fragments;
        private static final String[] TITLES = new String[] { "LOGIN", "HOME" };

        public static final int NUM_TITLES = TITLES.length;

        @Override
        public String getTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        public CustomFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
                List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // return this.fragments.size();
            return NUM_TITLES;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            try {
                LoginActivity.class.newInstance();
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return this.fragments.get(position);

        }

    }

}
```

**lcmeter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+android:id/titles"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nsixty.crew.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <support-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon87"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="ViewPagerFragment"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.main" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".play"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.play" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
                    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".secondView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.SECONDVIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".recorder"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.RECORD" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".send"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.SHARE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".gallery"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.gallery" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".media"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.media" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="CustomTitleBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

</manifest>
```

**ScreenShot1**
[image: LoginActivity activity]

**ScreenShot2**
[image: Sliding to main activity]

Please help me with these tiny problem i just can't figure out where the problem is coming from, i have been working for these for hours. i think the problem will be coming from the Xml layout thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this library [View pager extensions](https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions) among them i used swipey tab view indicator instead of Title page indicator and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);

    // Create our custom adapter to supply pages to the viewpager.
    mPagerAdapter = new Pager_Adapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    // Start at a custom position
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

     // Find the indicator from the layout
    mTabs = (TitleIndicator) findViewById(R.id.swipeytabs);
    mTabs.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    // Set the indicator as the pageChangeListener
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mTabs);

}

class Pager_Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewpagerAdapter{


    private final Context mContext;

    public Pager_Adapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        this.mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {

        return ItemFragment.newInstance(QUES[pos],listArray[pos]);
        //return ItemFragment.newInstance(QUES[pos % TITLES.length]);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    public TextView getTab(final int position, TitleIndicator root) {
        TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.swipey_tab_indicator, root, false);

                             //  swipey_tab_indicator is the your titleBar Layout ,
                              //  You can use only textview on that layout for the titlebar
        view.setText(TITLES[position]);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

For the more Information check this
[link](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tree/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample)

Comment: Hi Patel thanks for replying, your code is geared towards tab page indicator am doing Title page indicator, can you please edit for title page indicator. Thank you

Comment: Pls check the given link, This link containing both `Title + Tab` indicator.Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it looks like that the defaut selected color for this text is Black and your background is so you should change it to another color in the android XML file.